# How to use two different packages together on the same data

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-packages

I have this two packages which i want to use [flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify) and [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore).
**linkify** turns urls and email in a text into clickable link while **readmore** cuts long text into shorter one and i want to use both of them in with the same text

```
String randomText = "DetectableTextField is published as a refinement of this isaackelechi2000@gmail.com package. hashtagale forces you to use hashtag, but this one allows you to detect anything you want. If you also want https://www.google.com to decorate At sign, you can do that by adding the argument decorateAtSign: true. "

//Using linkify
Linkify(
  onOpen: (link) => print("Clicked ${link.url}!"),
  text: randomText,
);

//using readmore
ReadMoreText(
  randomText,
  trimLines: 2,
  colorClickableText: Colors.pink,
  trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
  trimCollapsedText: 'Show more',
  trimExpandedText: 'Show less',
  moreStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
);
```

So how can i use the both packages with the same text without showing two different text on the same screen

Comment: I have the exact same issue/question. Were you ever able to figure this out, or did you have to use a different package as suggested below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, since each of these widgets takes a string (rather than a child widget), they cannot be composed with each other.

I think you're best bet is to use the [ExpandablePanel](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) widget, instead of `ReadMoreText`, and then use `Linkify` on the child widgets.

Something like this might work (though you'll probably have to tweak for your exact use case).

```
ExpandablePanel(
  collapsed: Linkify(article.body, softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
  expanded: Linkify(article.body, softWrap: true, ),
  tapHeaderToExpand: true,
  hasIcon: true,
);
```