# Flutter : read more and hashtags in text

Tags: flutter, dart, instagram, hashtag

I want to have an Instagram like caption with "more.." and hashtags . I use [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore) package for "more..." and [hashtagable](https://github.com/santa112358/hashtagable) package for hashtags . But I want to combine these two . Each package has a Text property that do not accept other package as text . Is there any solution or package to have hashtags and "more..." together in one text ?

I can solve this with expandable package instead of readmore package like this

```
ExpandableNotifier(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Expandable(
                                          collapsed: HashTagText(
                                            text: postCaption,
                                            decoratedStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.blue),
                                            basicStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                            onTap: (text) {
                                              print(text);
                                            },
                                            softWrap: true,
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                          expanded: HashTagText(
                                            text: postCaption,
                                            decoratedStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontFamily: 'IranSans',
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.blue),
                                            basicStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                            onTap: (text) {
                                              print(text);
                                            },
                                            softWrap: true,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Builder(
                                              builder: (context) {
                                                var controller =
                                                    ExpandableController.of(
                                                        context,
                                                        required: true)!;
                                                return TextButton(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    controller.expanded
                                                        ? "less..."
                                                        : "more...",
                                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                                        .textTheme
                                                        .button!
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .deepPurple),
                                                  ),
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    controller.toggle();
                                                  },
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

**But "more" and "less" show always even text is 1 line only**

what is the solution ?

Comment: It is quite hard to help you without seeing your code or your attempt to combine these two. You should provide more information.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? @mm sh

Comment: @KishanSomaiya yes . look bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) package instead of readmore package . I removed readmore package then I placed hashtagable pacjage in expandable with help of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68866173/how-to-use-two-different-packages-together-on-the-same-data) like this

```
ExpandableNotifier(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Expandable(
                                          collapsed: HashTagText(
                                            text: postCaption,
                                            decoratedStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.blue),
                                            basicStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                            onTap: (text) {
                                              print(text);
                                            },
                                            softWrap: true,
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                          expanded: HashTagText(
                                            text: postCaption,
                                            decoratedStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontFamily: 'IranSans',
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.blue),
                                            basicStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                            onTap: (text) {
                                              print(text);
                                            },
                                            softWrap: true,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Builder(
                                              builder: (context) {
                                                var controller =
                                                    ExpandableController.of(
                                                        context,
                                                        required: true)!;
                                                return TextButton(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    controller.expanded
                                                        ? "less..."
                                                        : "more...",
                                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                                        .textTheme
                                                        .button!
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .deepPurple),
                                                  ),
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    controller.toggle();
                                                  },
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

> For But "more" and "less" show always even text is 1 line only
>
> what is the solution ?

You can use length of the text to show more/less, I've used 150 characters for 2 lines.